# Update Glance view in WatchKit

Tags: swift, watchkit

Hello I'm a newbie in programming, but I wanna learn. Here is my simple code in swift, how can I update the the illegalAt label every time when I open the glance view and then display updated value if any. Thank you very much for the help

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class GlanceInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var illegalAt: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        let  sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.birkyboy.TodayExtensionSharingDefaults")

        let illAt = sharedDefaults?.objectForKey("illegalAT") as! String
        illegalAt.setHidden(false)
        illegalAt.setText(illAt)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time your Glance is displayed, `willActivate` is called. That's the appropriate place to update your `illegalAt` label.

Comment: It does work like clockwork. Thank you very much for the help